# Scope of variable in golang

Tags: function, go, scope

I am trying to run one function in golang but I am getting some errors. Can anyone please help.

```
func exportVal(name string, value string){
    var ops = isWindows()
    if ops == true{
        set name=value
        fmt.Printf("name=")

    }else{
        export name=value
        fmt.Printf("name=")
   }
}
```

But I am getting below error.

```
D:\Go>go run octa.go
# command-line-arguments
.\octa.go:42:10: syntax error: unexpected name at end of statement
.\octa.go:46:13: syntax error: unexpected name at end of statement
```

Answer (score 1):

`set` and `export` are not [Go keywords](https://golang.org/ref/spec). Maybe you're thinking of shell? It looks like you're trying to set and export environment variables.

You cannot export environment variables from one process to another. You can only change your own process's environment. Child processes will inherit the parent's environment, but you can't go the other way. You can only do it in a shell program because that "program" is really a set of commands to the shell itself, and only then when using [`source something.sh`](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do). `sh something.sh`, in contrast, is run in a new shell process.

If you want to "export" data from a non-shell program, you'll have to print out the data in some format, [JSON](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) is a good choice, and have that be read by the other process.

Answer (score -1):

Go doesn't support the `export` keyword.

Are you trying to create a variable with global scope?

```
var foo string

func SetFoo(to string) {
    foo = to
}
```

Or are you trying to set an environment variable? In which case, use `os.Setenv(key, value)`.

Comment: Note that [`os.Setenv`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Setenv) will only set the environment variable for the Go process and any of its children. Probably not what is intended.

Comment: It can be helpful when using Go as a bash alternative and using the `exec` package to run processes.